# How to Create A Thumbnail Using Ionic Native

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to create a thumbnail from from video on a remove server using the video editor plugin, but just cant get it to work.
The thumbnail doesnt get created.
Below is my code:

```
private createThumbnail(remoteFileUrl: string) {
    this.thumbnailOptions = {
        atTime: 60,
        height: 1024,
        width: 1024,
        quality: 100,
        fileUrl: remoteFileUrl, // looks something like this : http://example.com/filename.mp4
        outputFileName: remoteFileUrl.substring(videoFile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
    };

    this.videoEditor.createThumbnail(this.thumbnailOptions).then(
        thumbnail => { this.thumbnail = thumbnail; },
        error => { this.thumbnail = '' }
    );
}
```

When i run this code i get the following error

"java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/http://example.com slash file name -> http://example.com slash file name

Answer (score 1):

Thats because the plugin does only support **local** video sources and you are trying to load one via the http protocol. Looking at the [sourecode](https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor/blob/54d31edb858b1fbefe1d1809d6289c48040e5669/src/android/VideoEditor.java) of the plugin you can find the following snippet in the `createThumbnail()` method:

```
String fileUri = options.getString("fileUri");
  if (!fileUri.startsWith("file:/")) {
    fileUri = "file:/" + fileUri;
  }
}
```

So if you pass a URI starting with *http* like in your example it will add `file:/` before it - of course - resulting in a `FileNotFoundException`.

You can try to fork the plugin and modify it according to your needs.

Comment: I had the same issue but with local file converting the thumbnail into base64 @David

Comment: Is there any other plugin or method available to solve this problem @David

Comment: any other plugin yet to create thumbnail image from video URL ?